# In Android, What is the x y origin value of Touch/click on app screen?

Tags: android

When I develop a app, I click at the up-left corner, I got x=0 y=59 or
something. How do I determine the y value? There are two rows above my
Touchable screen in my app:
1 first line/row is a tool/status bar which I don't know how to access
it
2. next line is my app name like "Hello World".
I think this two play a role to determine the y value.
How do I termine origin y value in my program?

-Henry

Comment: If you're using [getX()/getY()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getX()) you should get coordinates relative to the view, and with [getRawX()/getRawY()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getRawX()) raw coordinates relative to the whole screen (are you using these by chance?).

Answer (score 1):

Try playing with `getRawX()` and `getRawY()` on your `MotionEvent`(assuming you aren't already)

More details in [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)

Comment: At the top left, I called getRawX() and getRawY() , and get x=0,y=50. But in my program, how do I know what is the minimum y value I have control over? Why not x=0 y=0? Where is the y=50 coming from?

Comment: Like bigstones said getX() and getY() get the coordinates relative to the View and not the screen. Those 50px come from the toolbar and titlebar.